# access tab1 viewmodel data in tab2 viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to access the values of tab 1 in tab 2 I am using the code below for that. Problem is that I don't know how to use value of tab 1 property in tab 2.

**xaml**

```
<Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem DataContext="{Binding Children[0]}" x:Name="Tab1" Header="Tab1" >
                <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
 Margin="176,132,0,0" Name="checkBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top"
 CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay}" Command="{Binding ResetPassword}"
                          />
                <!-- Tab content -->
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem DataContext="{Binding Children[1]}" x:Name="Tab2" Header="Tab2" >
                <Label Content="{Binding IsChecked}"  ></Label>
                <!-- Tab content -->
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>

    </Grid>
```

**MainViewModel**

```
class MainViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<object> _children;
public MainViewModel()
{
    _children = new ObservableCollection<object>();
    _children.Add(new Tab1ViewModel());
    _children.Add(new Tab2ViewModel());
}

public ObservableCollection<object> Children { get { return _children; } }

}
```

In the above demo I am trying to use tab 1 Checkbox value in tab 2 viewmodel and trying to print it on a label in tab 2.

Comment: There are many of doing it. If you are using MVVMLight, then you can use messenger class, if you are using PRISM then you can use EventAggregator or PubSubEvents. If you are not using any frameworks then you can use normal .net events.